# Trying to recursively find the area of a polygon

Tags: java, recursion

Trying to calculate the area of a polygon recursively using the shoelace theorem and splitting it into triangles.

```
public static double calculatePolygonArea(ArrayList<Point> points) {
    if (points.size() < 3) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (points.size() == 3) {
        return calculateTriangleArea(points.get(0), points.get(1), points.get(2));
    }
       
    return calculateTriangleArea(points.get(0), points.get(1), points.get(2)) +
           calculatePolygonArea(new ArrayList<>(points.subList(1, points.size())));
}

private static double calculateTriangleArea(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3) {
    return Math.abs((p1.getX() * p2.getY() + p2.getX() * p3.getY() + p3.getX() * p1.getY()
            - p1.getY() * p2.getX() - p2.getY() * p3.getX() - p3.getY() * p1.getX()) / 2.0);
}
```

The code does not return the correct area and its always less than the actual area.

Comment: Does `calculateTriangleArea` return the correct value? If you log the calls to `calculateTriangleArea` is the polygon being correctly decomposed? There is so much debugging that you could have done before asking this question!

Comment: not sure if that really is the *Shoelace Theorem* -- As shown on [Wikipedia] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula), the formula uses some arbitrary (fixed) point common to all triangles (and the area is *allowed* to be negative)

Comment: Note that the order of the `Point`s in the `ArrayList` is important. The [polygon] vertices must be listed in counter-clockwise order. Note that the code in your question works for me. I tested a right-angle triangle, a rectangle and a trapezium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem stems from how you're reducing the polygon's points. (You're forming a triangle with the first three points and then removing the second point from the list for the next recursion.) While this should *theoretically* work for convex polygons, ensuring that all triangles are valid, it doesn't handle the geometrical relationships properly, leading you to get a low-balled area.

here's a possible fix:

```java
public static double calculatePolygonArea(ArrayList<Point> points) {
  if (points.size() < 3) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (points.size() == 3) {
    return calculateTriangleArea(points.get(0), points.get(1), points.get(2));
  }

  ArrayList<Point> newPoints = new ArrayList<>(points);

  newPoints.remove(1); // remove the point that was just used

  return calculateTriangleArea(points.get(0), points.get(1), points.get(2))
      + calculatePolygonArea(newPoints); // recurse with the updated list of points
}
```

this ensures the first point is always used as a vertex in the triangles being formed

this does assume you're using convex polygons, for non-convex polygons this approach probably won't accurately calculate the area due to assuming that a direct line between points does not intersect the polygon itself

---

**edit**: unneeded, but fun optimization
a further optimization would be to avoid creating new lists, you could do this by using indices to track the current "view" of the polygon, which would decrease memory usage significantly.

```java
public static double calculatePolygonArea(ArrayList<Point> points) {
  return calculateAreaRecursive(points, 0, points.size());
}

// overloaded recursive function using indices
private static double calculateAreaRecursive(
    ArrayList<Point> points, int start, int end) {
  int n = end - start;
  if (n < 3) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (n == 3) {
    return calculateTriangleArea(
        points.get(start), points.get(start + 1), points.get(start + 2));
  }

  double triangleArea = calculateTriangleArea(
      points.get(start), points.get(start + 1), points.get(end - 1));

  return triangleArea + calculateAreaRecursive(points, start + 1, end);
}
```